# Copy 1D array to multidimensional array - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I have two functions in VBA. Function1 returns a 1D array. Then I have function2 which is a multidimensional array. I would like to copy the array in Function1 to the columns of the multidimensional array starting at index 1.

```
arr2(0,0) = "Something"
arr2(0,1) = ("Something",arr1(0))
arr2(0,2) = ("Something",arr1(1))
```

This is what I have. arr1 is GetRecData and arr2 is AllChannelsData.

```
For i = 0 To UBound(channelList)
    'the first row in the array is the channels names
    AllChannelsData(i, 0) = channelList(i)
    Set RecChannel = Rec.FindChannel(channelList(i), RecDevice.Name)
    For j = 0 To total_time
        AllChannelsData(i, j + 1) = RecChannelData.GetRecData(RecChannel, 1, 0)
    Next
Next
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer the code below.

```
Sub Array_test()
    Dim GetRecData(9) As String
    Dim AllChannelsData(9, 2) As String
    For i = 0 To 9
        GetRecData(i) = i
        For j = 0 To 9
            AllChannelsData(j, 0) = j
            AllChannelsData(j, 1) = GetRecData(j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
For j = 0 To total_time
    AllChannelsData(i, j + 1) = RecChannelData.GetRecData(RecChannel, 1, 0)
Next
```

to this

```
For j = 0 To total_time
    AllChannelsData(i, j + 1) = RecChannelData.GetRecData(RecChannel, 1, j)
Next
```

maybe?

I'm assuming the third parameter of the `.GetRecData(RecChannel, 1, 0)` method is the index since 1D arrays like you're describing don't take 3 parameters. If that's not it, you may need to expand on what the `GetRecData` method is/does/returns/etc.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The third parameter it's not the index. The GetRecData method needs the three parameters to return a 1D array.

Answer (score 0):

this "base" code works

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim arr2() As Variant
Dim total_time As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

total_time = 4

ReDim arr2(0 To 3, 0 To total_time)
For i = 0 To 3
    arr2(i, 0) = i
    For j = 1 To total_time
        arr2(i, j) = GetRecData(j + 1)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub

Function GetRecData(n As Integer) As Variant
ReDim arr(0 To n - 1) As Variant
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To n
    arr(i - 1) = i
Next i

GetRecData = arr
End Function
```

just adapt it to your needs